# SpringJDBC Datasource Connection Set Type Map

Tags: datasource, spring-jdbc

Hi I want to set mytypemappings to connection but I cant change datasource type mappings.setType map not work.

DataSource javax.sql,

> ```
>      Map map = dataSource.getConnection().getTypeMap();
>     map.put("mytpe", myclass);
>    connection = dataSource.getConnection();
>     connection.setTypeMap(map);//(connection set and when I get I see type map)
>    dataSource.getConnection().setTypeMap(map);//(connection set and when I get I cant see type map)
> ```

```
     DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(connectionstringinfos);

        Map<String,Class<Object> map2= dataSource.getConnection().getTypeMap();
        map2.put("mymap",MyMap.class);
        dataSource.getConnection().setTypeMap(map2);
dataSource.getConnection().getTypeMap();-->that time mymap does not seen
```

Comment: what is not working ? any error ?  what is the expectation ?

Comment: no errors but when I make a query again like dataSource.getConnection().getTypeMap() that time my previous added map not seen in this list

Comment: Please share the complete code .

Comment: I add sample,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call `dataSource.getConnection()` you get a new `Connection` instance, so you need to add the type map to every new instance.